# Icons Affecting Menu Style in wxPython on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, menu, wxpython, highlighting

The following bit of code populates a class that inherits from the **wx.Menu** class, with menu items. So **self** is basically a wx.Menu. When I run the flowing code snippet, the line **about.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('Icon24.ico'))** seems to change the highlighting from the default:

[image]

to this plain blue style:

[image]

The line **about.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('Icon24.ico'))** simply adds an icon (test). But, for some reason it changes the highlighting style. I know this is about as nitpicky as it gets, but I'd like to the first images highlighting style with the second images Icon. This is in Windows 7 if it makes a difference.

Snippet:

```
about =  wx.MenuItem(self, -1, 'About...')
about.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('Icon24.ico')) # The line that's causing the problem. 

itemlist = [self.AppendItem(about),
            self.AppendSeparator(),
            self.Append(-1, 'Options...'),
            self.AppendSeparator(),
            self.Append(-1, 'Exit')]

for i in itemlist:
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.menu_beh, i)
```

Comment: Which version of wxWidgets/wxPython are you using?

Comment: wxPython version 2.8.11.0, in Python 2.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the WxWidgets doc, the version 2.8 doesn't support Windows Vista or 7, so I think this is expected since looks like it reset the entire menu theme to the XP style, I think the best you can try is to use the testing version 2.9, which support Vista (but not 7).